# The @ObservedResults loads old data in View on deletion, creation or update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm

### Description

I've got simple `Combat` model which stores `name` and list of `actors`. When I delete the `Combat` from `List` using `onDelete` it looks like it's working. It removes  the  `Combat` from Realm (checked with RealmStudio) and updates the view. However, if view gets redrawn (for instance, when switching Apps), the "old" data is loaded again (the very first loaded on app initialization), so all deleted rows are back again. Of course, removing them again crashes the app, because they are not present in `@ObservedResults combats` anymore. Restarting the app fixes the issue, because new data is loaded to `@ObservedResults combats` and to `List`, but then again, when I removed something it will be back on review draw...

What I discovered is that removing `.sheet()` **fixes** the issue! (**EDIT**: clarification; it doesn't matter what's inside of the `sheet`, it may be even empty) The view is updated correctly on redraw! The `Sheet` is used to display form to add new `Combat` (nether to say that adding new combats or editing them **does not** update the view as well, but let's focus on deletion). I have no idea what adding `sheet()` changes in behaviour of the List and "listening" to `@ObservedResults combats`.

As a test I used simple array of `Combat` classes and **everything worked**. So it points me to issue with `@ObservedResults`.

I was using the `Alert` before and all changes to `@ObservedResults combats` were seen at glance. Now I wanted to replace Alert with Sheet and… That happened.

Also, I have subview where I have almost identical code for `actor` and there everything works, however I use `@ObservedRealmObject var combat: Combat` there, and I pass the combat `@ObservedResults combats`, like so:

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: CombatView(combat: combat)) { Text(combat.name) }
```

I removed unecessary code from below examples to keep it at minimum.

### Model

The `Combat` model:

```swift
class Combat: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    var actors = List<Actor>()
}
```

### Actual View Code (broken using Sheet)

```swift
@ObservedResults(
        Combat.self,
        sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor( keyPath: "name", ascending: true)
    ) var combats

struct CombatsListView: View {
    
    @ObservedResults(
        Combat.self,
        sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor( keyPath: "name", ascending: true)
    ) var combats
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(combats) { combat in
                Text(combat.name)
            }.onDelete(perform: $combats.remove)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddCombat) {
            AddCombatView( showAddCombat: $showAddCombat)
        }
    }
}
```

### Old View Code (works using Alert)

```swift
struct CombatsListView: View {

@ObservedResults(
        Combat.self,
        sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor( keyPath: "name", ascending: true)
    ) var combats

@State private var showAddCombat = false
@State private var addCombatNewName = ""

var body: some View {
        List(combats) { combat in
            Text(combat.name)
            .onDelete(perform: $combats.remove)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    showAlert = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus" )
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("New Combat")
                }.alert("New Combat", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    TextField("write name", text: $addCombatNewName)
                    Button("Close", role: .cancel) {
                        addCombatNewName = ""
                    }
                    Button("Add") {
                        addNewCombat(name: addCombatNewName)
                        addCombatNewName = ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addNewCombat(name: String) {
        let newCombat = Combat()
        newCombat.name = name
        do {
            try self.realm.write {
                realm.add(newCombat)
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

## EDITED

I just found some new behaviour. I made a new simple view which lists elements of `Collection` list and you can delete or add new `Collection`. It works just fine, but if I include this `CollectionsView` under the `TabView`, then the effect is exactly the same as in the example above. The view stops working properly: deleted items are added back on view redraw and adding new objects doesn't refresh the View.

This makes me think more of a bug in `@ObservedResults()`.

Below is the source code.

```swift
class Collection: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    var actors = List<Actor>()
}
```

```swift
@main
struct CombatTrackerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Tabber() // will not work
//            CollectionsView() // will work
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct CollectionsView: View {
    
    @ObservedResults( Collection.self ) var collections
    
    @State private var showNewCollectionForm = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(collections) { collection in
                        Text(collection.name)
                }.onDelete(perform: $collections.remove)
            }
            .listStyle(.inset)
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Collections")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button() {
                        self.showNewCollectionForm.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                        Text("Add New Collection")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showNewCollectionForm) {
                NewCollectionView( showNewCollectionForm: $showNewCollectionForm )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct NewCollectionView: View {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    @Binding var showNewCollectionForm: Bool
    @State private var newCollectioName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Create new Collection").font(.title).padding()
                Form {
                    TextField("Name", text: $newCollectioName)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Close", role: .cancel) {
                        showNewCollectionForm.toggle()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button("Create") {
                        addCollection()
                    } .disabled(newCollectioName.isEmpty)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addCollection() {
        let newCollection = Collection()
        newCollection.name = newCollectioName
        
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(newCollection)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Cannot add new Collection", error)
        }
        showNewCollectionForm.toggle()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct Tabber: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            NavigationStack {
                CombatsListView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Combats")
            }
            NavigationStack {
                CollectionsView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Collections")
            }
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Settings")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; it states that when using a Sheet, it doesn't work, but the question doesn't include the sheet code so we don't know what it does. Are you saying by just having this code `.sheet(isPresented: $showAddCombat) {` the `.onDelete` does not work? Or it doesn't work after you opened the sheet or... ? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my primary language. Just by adding `.sheet(isPresented: $showAddCombat) {}` the `.onDelete` stops working. Even with empty `sheet` block. Also, adding or updating `combats` doesn't updates the `List` view. It looks like `ObservedResults combats` is not registering any changes. Switching `@ObservedResults combats` to regular array of `[Combat]` works. Using `@ObservedResults` it stops. When I switch `sheet` with `alert`, all works again.

Comment: I added new example where adding view under `TabView` breaks `@ObservedResults()` behaviour the same way as my initial code. I think it's a bug in `@ObservedResults()` or I clearly miss some important point here :)

Comment: For clarification: you're using `@ObservedRealmObject` and `@ObservedResults` - both of those are designed as wrappers to let you interact with your realm data without explicitly opening write transactions, but the code opens write transactions within the views. Why not just use those wrappers? Also, you should be transitioning your models away from the `@objc dynamic var` and into the modern `@Persisted var` syntax. Lastly, I am surprised the compiler isn't yelling at you for this `var actors = List<Actor>()` as `List` is a Swift collision. It needs to be `RealmSwift.List<Actor>()`

Comment: It's just the example, it doesn't matter if using transaction block or appending `$combats` (tried both solutions, pasted above one of them). Regarding `@Persisted var` I didn't know that, thanks for the tip! Regarding List in Swift Xcode doesn't yell because in model I do not include `SwiftUI` but `Foundation`.

Comment: I found out that if `TabView` is inside `NavigationStack`, then `@ObservedResults( Collection.self ) var collections` works fine and List is properly refreshed. But if every tab has own `NavigationStack` then it doesn't refresh the View anymore.

Comment: Sorry for many comments, but I *think* I found the issue. It was related to `NavigationStack`. Turns out that I need to remove `NavigationStack` from my `Tabber` view and move to each of views (`CombatsListView` and `CollectionsView`). Now Collections are refreshed correctly on new addition and on deletion, and tooolbars and titles are working properly. However, I have no clue why NavigationStack couldn't be defined in Tabber but must be in subview and why it broke the `List` redraw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution (but I still don't understand why it's working).

The solution was to move `NavigationStack` from my `TabView` to the subviews. So instead of:

```swift
struct Tabber: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            NavigationStack {
                CombatsListView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Combats")
            }
//...
```

I should do:

```swift
struct Tabber: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            CombatsListView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Combats")
            }
//...
```

```swift
struct CombatsListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
```

Confusing part was that all online tutorials and Apple Documentation suggests to wrap subviews with `NavigationStack` in `TabView` directly instead of adding `NavigationStack` in subviews. Maybe it's a bug, maybe it's a feature.